# How to set a date visibility Catalina OS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina

Now I see a date on the top bar in such format

[image]

But I would like to change it that I can see also a date, like this(for example`

`Fri 10.11.19 10:13`

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it hasn't suddenly changed in Catalina after being the same for years…

System Prefs > Date & Time > Clock

Check Show date

[image]

As far as I'm aware, there is no option to change the displayed date format. It will use your Language & Region prefs for that, but adjusting date formats in there does not affect the clock display.